# Proving $\sum \limits_{i=0}^k {n \choose i}(-1)^i = {n-1 \choose k}(-1)^k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, binomial-coefficients

What proof could I use to prove the following identity? I somehow know that Pascal's identity must be used but I need some help. Could anyone show me how to solve this? maybe by induction or combinatorial proof, it would be awesome to have both:
$\sum \limits_{i=0}^k {n \choose i}(-1)^i = {n-1 \choose k}(-1)^k$

Comment: Using induction, if $$\sum_{i=0}^m\binom ni(-1)^i=\binom{n-1}m(-1)^m$$


$$\sum_{i=0}^{m+1}\binom ni(-1)^i=\binom{n-1}m(-1)^m+\binom n{m+1}(-1)^{m+1}$$ 

which needs to be $$\binom{n-1}{m+1}(-1)^{m+1}$$

$$\iff\binom{n-1}m-\binom n{m+1}=\binom{n-1}{m+1}$$

Comment: why does the last equality hold? @labbhattacharjee

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Please post that as a answer.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I have the same induction procedure but it I divided by $(-1)^m$ and the signs of the last equality on the left hand side are different but I don't get the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(k)$ be the statement 
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{k} \binom{n}{i}(-1)^i = \binom{n - 1}{k}(-1)^k$$

Let $k = 0$.  Then 
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{0} \binom{n}{i}(-1)^i = \binom{n}{0}(-1)^0 = 1 \cdot 1 = \binom{n - 1}{0}(-1)^0$$
Thus, $P(0)$ holds.

Since $P(0)$ holds, we may assume $P(m)$ holds for some nonnegative integer $m$.  Then 
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{m} \binom{n}{i}(-1)^i = \binom{n - 1}{m}(-1)^m$$
Let $k = m + 1$.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 0}^{m + 1} \binom{n}{i}(-1)^k & = \sum_{i = 0}^{m + 1} \binom{n}{i}(-1)^k + \binom{n}{m + 1}(-1)^{m + 1}\\
& = \binom{n - 1}{m}(-1)^m + \binom{n}{m + 1}(-1)^{m + 1} && \text{induction hypothesis}\\
& = -\binom{n - 1}{m}(-1)^{m + 1} + \binom{n}{m + 1}(-1)^{m + 1}\\
& = \left[-\binom{n - 1}{m} + \binom{n}{m + 1}\right](-1)^{m + 1}\\
& = \binom{n - 1}{m + 1}(-1)^{m + 1} 
\end{align*}
where we have used Pascal's Identity 
$$\binom{n - 1}{k} + \binom{n - 1}{k - 1} = \binom{n}{k}$$
with $k = m + 1$ in the final step.  Therefore, $P(m) \implies P(m + 1)$.

Since $P(0)$ holds and $P(m) \implies P(m + 1)$, $P(k)$ holds for each nonnegative integer $k$.

Note that the claim does hold for $k > n - 1$.  If $k > n - 1$, the right hand side vanishes.  The only nonzero terms on the left hand side are those for which $k \leq n$.  If $k = n$, then 
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}(-1)^i = \sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{n}{i}1^{n - i}(-1)^i = [1 + (-1)]^n = 0^n = 0$$
by the Binomial Theorem.